# I'm getting error for executing commands on cell phone (nfc-card emulation mode), "6E00": "Class not supported"

Tags: authentication, command, nfc, mifare

I have pc/sc reader which completely works with mifare 1k card I've executed "get data","load key","authenticate","read"commands and all of them work correctly.now I want to work with nfc on cell phone but when I've tried these commands on it (I have cell phone with embeded element(smartMX) which as I know it  must support mifare 1k commands ) I just could execute "get data" command but for the rest of them I saw this error  "6E00": "Class not supported"

```
Card ATR: 3B8A80010031C173C8400000900090
```

here is the list of the commands that I've used for mifare 1k card

```
GetData <FF CA 00 00 00>
LoadkeyN<FF 82 20 00 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF>
Authentication<FF 88  00 60 00>
```

Dose any one know which class or commands I must use?I'll be grateful  for any suggestion or information.